# PySpark Dataframe Groupby and Count Null Values

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark

I have a Spark Dataframe of the following form:

```
+------+-------+-----+--------+
| Year | Month | Day | Ticker |
+------+-------+-----+--------+
```

I am trying to group all of the values by "year" and count the number of missing values in each column per year.

I found the following snippet (forgot where from):

```
df.select(*(sum(col(c).isNull().cast("int")).alias(c) for c in df.columns)).show()
```

This works perfectly when calculating the number of missing values per column. However, I'm not sure how I would modify this to calculate the missing values per year.

Any pointers in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can just use the same logic and add a `groupby`. Note that I also removed "year" from the aggregated columns, but that's optional (you would get two 'year' columns).

```
columns = filter(lambda x: x != "year", df.columns)
df.groupBy("year")\
  .agg(*(sum(col(c).isNull().cast("int")).alias(c) for c in columns))\
  .show()
```

Comment: Cheers; I tried this but received an error before, not sure why.

Comment: Ah, my bad, I had not replaced "select" with "agg" which was causing the error. Thank you for the help :-)