# Pyspark groupby and count null values

Tags: pyspark

[PySpark Dataframe Groupby and Count Null Values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55265954/pyspark-dataframe-groupby-and-count-null-values/67565028#67565028)

Referring to the solution link above, I am trying to apply the same logic but groupby("country") and getting the null count of another column, and I am getting a "column is not iterable" failure. Can someone help with this?

```
df7.groupby("country").agg(*(sum(col(c).isNull().cast("int")).alias(c) for c in columns))
```

Comment: did you import sum from pyspark sql functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
covid_india_df.select(
    [
        funcs.count(
            funcs.when((funcs.isnan(clm) | funcs.col(clm).isNull()), clm)
        ).alias(clm) for clm in covid_india_df.columns
    ]
).show()
```

The above approach may help you to get correct results. [Check here](https://github.com/Evergreenies/data_engineering_pyspark/blob/main/pyspark_scripts/india_covid_19_analysis.ipynb) for a complete example.

Comment: In this case it worked when summing the entire column but i needed it to be grouped by year, so i tried the following, df7.groupby("country").agg(F.count(F.when((F.isnan(c) | F.col(c).isNull()), c)).alias(c) for c in columns).show()      and in this case i received "all exprs should be Column" error